# Can we pass build time as parameter in Jenkins jobs.?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a job in jenkins which triggers other pipelines. Is there any way in which I can pass the time, as parameter, at which the job must run a certain pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/), there is `quietPeriod` parameter that you may want to explore.

```
* quietPeriod (optional)

Optional alternate quiet period (in seconds) before building. If unset, defaults 
to the quiet period defined by the downstream project (or finally to the system-
wide default quiet period).

Type: int
```

You need to calculate the amount of seconds between "now" and when you want the job to run.